# I am getting this error while building a pjsip project in codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks, pjsip

> gcc -Wall  -g      -c /Users/prateek/Documents/pjsip/main.c -o obj/Debug/main.o
>   g++  -o bin/Debug/pjsip obj/Debug/main.o
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_hex_string_to_octet_string", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_caching_pool_destroy", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_caching_pool_init", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_getopt_long", referenced from:
>         _get_snd_options in main.o
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_gettimeofday", referenced from:
>         _print_stream_stat in main.o
>     "_pj_inet_ntoa", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_init", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_log_3", referenced from:
>         _app_perror in main.o
>         _get_snd_options in main.o
>         _dump_pool_usage in main.o
>     "_pj_log_get_level", referenced from:
>         _app_perror in main.o
>         _get_snd_options in main.o
>         _dump_pool_usage in main.o
>     "_pj_ntohs", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_optarg", referenced from:
>         _get_snd_options in main.o
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_optind", referenced from:
>         _get_snd_options in main.o
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_optopt", referenced from:
>         _get_snd_options in main.o
>     "_pj_pool_create", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_pool_factory_default_policy", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_pool_get_capacity", referenced from:
>         _dump_pool_usage in main.o
>     "_pj_pool_get_used_size", referenced from:
>         _dump_pool_usage in main.o
>     "_pj_pool_release", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_rand", referenced from:
>         _create_stream in main.o
>     "_pj_shutdown", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_sockaddr_in_init", referenced from:
>         _create_stream in main.o
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_str", referenced from:
>         _create_stream in main.o
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pj_strerror", referenced from:
>         _app_perror in main.o
>     "_pj_time_val_normalize", referenced from:
>         _print_stream_stat in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_codec_mgr_find_codecs_by_id", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_codec_mgr_get_codec_info", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_codec_mgr_get_default_param", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_codec_register_audio_codecs", referenced from:
>         _init_codecs in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_endpt_create", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_endpt_destroy", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_endpt_get_codec_mgr", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_master_port_create", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_master_port_destroy", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_master_port_start", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_port_destroy", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_snd_port_connect", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_snd_port_create", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_snd_port_create_player", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_snd_port_create_rec", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_snd_port_destroy", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_stream_create", referenced from:
>         _create_stream in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_stream_destroy", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_stream_get_port", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>         _print_stream_stat in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_stream_get_stat", referenced from:
>         _print_stream_stat in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_stream_get_transport", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_stream_start", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_transport_srtp_create", referenced from:
>         _create_stream in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_transport_srtp_start", referenced from:
>         _create_stream in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_transport_udp_create", referenced from:
>         _create_stream in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_wav_player_port_create", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>     "_pjmedia_wav_writer_port_create", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to link to some library. You should tell the linker about this library in "Build Options" -> "Linker Settings".

I don't have your code so I can only guess, but I think you are trying to use pjmedia without linking to it.

Comment: Yes i have added `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject` but then also it is not working whereas it is working in the terminal when i run like gcc filename `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject` and one more thing i m using macbook pro

Comment: @pratick Simply try adding -lpjproject to "other linker flags".

Comment: It is also not working basically when i add something in linker options and then try to build then when I check the build log it is coming like "g++  -o bin/Debug/pjsip obj/Debug/main.o" whereas it should come as "g++  -o bin/Debug/pjsip obj/Debug/main.o something something " becoz of the thing that i add in the linker options